# requirejS how to simply use it to include a JS file.

Tags: requirejs

I've been tasked with implementing requireJS.

Prior to the cleanup we had something like this :

```
<!--jQuery-->
<!--It's included in script/config.js above-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/jquery-ui-layout-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery plugin for session -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/jquery.session.js"></script>
```

Now using RequireJS, the result is:

HTML :

```
<script data-main="script/includes" src="./script/require.js"></script>
```

Looks cleaner already, and then inside includes.js:

```
var jquery = "jquery-latest.min";
var jqueryUI = "jquery-ui-latest.min";
var jqueryUILayout = "jquery-ui-layout-latest.min";
var jquerySession = "jquery.session";
```

and the big call to:

```
require([config, jquery, jqueryUI, jqueryUILayout, jquerySession, basicAjax, json, requestObject
        , uiBasic, uiElementHelper, uiFormCheck, uiTableHelper, suggest, framework, constants, eselcs], function ($) {
            alert("something happened");
        });
```

But the scripts simply aren't working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are the scripts not working?? You get an error on the console? You get no error, but the `alert` is not coming up? Something else happens? What is in your `includes.js`? Does it contain *only* lines like the variable declarations and then a single `require` call? Is it the output from using the optimizer? Please edit your question with this information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using multiple calls to require. Not sure if this is how it's done but couldn't find any other way to do it.